# Access a self-hosted WCF service from the internet and LAN

Tags: web-services, wcf, web, host, lan

I have a self-hosted wcf service on a pc in the office. The service address is the IPv4 of the PC + port + / service / ERP.
So that the client application can access from the LAN, it uses the address of the server as I mentioned, and to access from outside the LAN, I use the public IPv4 or a url of some DNS provider and in the Reuter I redirect the port to the PC where the service is hosted. So far everything works perfectly, the problem I have is that the notebooks must access from inside the LAN and sometimes from outside, but if I use public IPv4 from within the network I cannot access the service.
My current solution is to have two configurations or two icons, one for internal access and another for external access where the user selects depending on their location, but I would like to have access and somehow be able to detect if it is on the LAN or on the outside, or if you know of any way to allow access from a LAN using a public IPv4

Comment: You need to configure two service endpoints in the client, one using internal IP and the other using external IP. If the client is on the internal network, use the service endpoint of the internal network; if the client is on the external network, use the service endpoint of the external network. Before calling the WCF service, you need to determine whether the client is an external network or an internal network in order to select the correct service endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for answering, is what I thought ...
The challenge is to determine whether or not you are on the LAN without having to wait for one to fail and try the other.

Comment: There should be two endpoint information in the client. Which endpoint to use depends on where the client accesses it from, so before calling, you must determine where the client will access the WCF service.